# Microsoft Speech API with Windows Store App yet?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, speech-recognition

Is the Microsoft Speech API usable now? I really need to use it with my project.
I need to receive some short keyword voice command and do the task as users want. Also, I'd like to use the text-to-speech

So far what I've found is that it can't be used with Windows Store Apps, but those answers were from like half year ago...

If anybody knows the answer or has a suggestion on any Speech API which I can use with my project, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: please refer <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx>

Answer (score 1):

When you say a "Windows Store App" I assume you mean an application developed for Windows RT. [Windows RT does support speech recognition](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/using-speech-recognition) as part of the OS, but finding information on how to incorporate them into your RT application is not easy to find. There is an [AT&T SDK that supports speech recognition](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1fb5b8ee-c981-4249-97a3-cccd2ecc664c). It looks like [IVONA supports text-to-speech](http://www.ivona.com/us/sdk/) on Windows RT/ARM processors.

Answer (score 0):

It is now available and here's an MSDN sample demonstrating its use:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Speech-synthesis-sample-6e07b218