# Is speech recognition API available in windows store app?

Tags: windows, speech-recognition

I am working on a windows store app, and intend to add tts to it. can anyone tell me whether speech recognition API available in windows store app?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009710/674700).

Answer (score 1):

Bing speech recognition control has been released recently. Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx